# Eclipse Code Refactoring - Junits

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I want to refactor exisiting code

```
String a = "Hi";
assertEquals(a, "Hi");
```

to

```
String a = "Hi";
assertEquals("Hi", a);
```

I have like 2 million assert statements all over my project that need to be refactored. Are they any shortcuts keys, templates or batch process in Eclipse IDE which I can implement to do this more easily?

> assertEquals(expected, actual);

Comment: I'd maybe use smth. like "Find and replace in project" function with a regex.

Comment: @ArthurEirich : Could you share an example of the regex expression?

Comment: Side note: when you go for all that work of refactoring, why not change it to the much more sane *assertThat(a, is("Hi"))*? Has the nice advantage that you wont need to swap your arguments ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat When talking about saneness I'd go further and use AssertJ instead of hamcrest. IMHO the code like `assertThat(a).isEqualTo("Hi")` is a bit more readable as in your suggestion. P.S. I'm still trying to find the right regex =)

Comment: @ArthurEirich Sure. I guess that depends what library you want to use. **assertThat** and **is** are things that most people will be able to use immediately - **without** the need of  adding a new dependency to a completely new assertion framework.

Comment: @ArthurEirich: Try [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718338/using-eclipse-find-and-replace-all-to-swap-arguments). The regex suggested in the answer is not working for me though.

Comment: @SRCM use notepad++ easy way to find and replace all occurrence of  assertEquals(a, "Hi"); by assertEquals("Hi", a)  from all files in directory. ctrl+F -> findinfiles

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the link. It helped a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

1. Copy `org.junit.Assert.assertEquals` methods into a new class, let's say `temp.TempAssert`
2. Search and replace `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;` with `import static temp.TempAssert.assertEquals;` in all files
3. Go to `TempAssert` class and do Refactor -> Change Method Signature to switch order of parameters
4. Replace `import static temp.TempAssert.assertEquals;` back to `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;` in all files

Comment: Nice idea that is.

Answer (score 1):

Having played a bit with the regex, I came up with the following solution (thanks to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718338/using-eclipse-find-and-replace-all-to-swap-arguments#7718458)):

```
assertEquals\((.*), (.*)\);
```

captures the first and the second argument into a separate group 1 and group 2 respectively and should be pasted into the `find` input field.

```
assertEquals($2, $1);
```

This command will swap the groups which were stored in $1 for the first and $2 for the second argument respectively.

**WARNING**

I am using Intellij IDEA for developing, thus it can come to an unexpected behaviour in eclipse. But the command should be almost the same ones.